# UIImagePickerController returns image with black background on right side when the property .allowsEditing is set to true

Tags: ios

I'm using UIImagePickerController for picking images from gallery. Here is the code

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    
    isfrompicker = true
    if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
       // I'm getting image with black background on right side as shown.
    }
}
```

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZDq0.jpg)

I'm not sure why I'm getting black background on right side. Same code is working fine on some devices. But I'm getting issue with my iPhone X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem a few ago.
Then i found a solution on
[Link to page](https://programmersought.com/article/5044848471/)

Try adding this line before presenting imagePicker

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
```